# Which types of datas can I use in a Jquery autocomplete example in JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

```
<%  
    UsrealmManager manager = new UsrealmManager();
    List<Usrealm> realmList = manager.realmlist();
%>
<select name="Realms">
<%for (Usrealm usrealm : realmList) {%>
<option value="<%=usrealm.getUsrealmId()%>"><%=usrealm.getRealmName()%>
</option>
<%}%>
</select>
```

I have a list of objects in JSP and filling the select tag with them.
I need to write an autocomple with Jquery but I cant use realmList on the javascript side. 
What should I do? I couldnt parse Java Object List to Json.

Comment: What should you do? Create another jsp that returns a list of options and call it via ajax, If you couldn't  *parse Java Object List to Json*, you still have an option to use html.

Comment: @RomanC Now I tried to write the Json in my Jsp in <script></script> tags. I am writing to down the code. II pleasure much if you guys comment, is it a good way or not.

Comment: You are writing [*spaghetti code*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) that generate a javascript code in the output html. As  [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/servlets-jsp-140445.html) article suggests you'd better create classes or servlets and put computations there.

Comment: @RomanC thanks for your answers, I have read all the page you refered. And understood what you mean "spaghetti code". You are saying "dont use too much java code or script codes in your jsp". Okey i got it but as i wrote down of page in the last comment of mine. I just need to know, is it a good way to create javascript list between jsp page's <script></script> tags. Or can you prefer me a better way to do it?

Comment: I dont know how to use java datas in javascript =( Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use autocomplete widget from jquery UI (https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).
With this plugin you can create a javascript array from java pojos and pass it to the autocomplete method.

Using the example on jquery UI sites:

```
<%  
  UsrealmManager manager = new UsrealmManager();
  List<Usrealm> realmList = manager.realmlist();
%>
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
    <%for (Usrealm usrealm : realmList) {%>
     { label: '<%=usrealm.getRealmName()%>', value: '<%=usrealm.getUsrealmId()%>' }
    <%}%>
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
</script>
```

Comment: tarini you said pojo. is it my realmList? And where I will change my realmList to javascript array. My question is exactly this. If you can give me a sample. It would be wonderful.

Comment: I improved my answer. Be careful that code is untested, is just an example to explain. PS use JSTL!

Comment: I dont think it would work because .js is in client side and java code is in server side. How could it be work in the same time?

Comment: It will work. From server side you output code that will be interpreted by client side engines.